# Initialize boost::hana::tuple with one argument

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming, generic-programming, boost-hana

Let's assume we have something like this: An Interface for some class Foo ( 'FooInterface' ) and a container class Bar that contains derived classes from 'FooInterface'.

Now I forward a typelist of the types of the derived classes ( 'FooOne', 'FooTwo' ) to the container class and it stores an instance of them in a 'boost::hana::tuple' subsequent to a small type computation ( 'FooTuple' ).

Now how do I initialize the tuple elements with a dereferenced this-pointer, depending on the size of 'FooList' ?

[MCVE (Wandbox)](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oJcaegRkUDAUGDCC)

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

template <typename FooList>
class Bar;

template <typename FooList>
class FooInterface
{
public:
    FooInterface(Bar<FooList>& bar) {}

public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class FooOne;
class FooTwo;

using MyFooList = decltype(hana::tuple_t<FooOne, FooTwo>);

class FooOne final
    : public FooInterface<MyFooList>
{
public:
    FooOne(Bar<MyFooList>& bar) 
        : FooInterface(bar)
    {}

public:
    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "FooOne!\n";
    }
};

class FooTwo final
    : public FooInterface<MyFooList>
{
public:
    FooTwo(Bar<MyFooList>& bar) 
        : FooInterface(bar)
    {}

public:
    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "FooTwo!\n";
    }
};

template <typename FooList>
class Bar
{
public:
    using FooTuple = typename decltype(hana::unpack(FooList(), hana::template_<hana::tuple>))::type;

    FooTuple foos{ *this, *this };
};

int main() 
{
   Bar<MyFooList> b;
   b.foos[hana::int_c<0>].foo();
   b.foos[hana::int_c<1>].foo();
}
```

Output :

```
FooOne!
FooTwo!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hana::replicate` is your friend.

```
template <typename FooList>
class Bar {
    ...

    using FooTuple = ...;
    FooTuple foos;

    Bar() : foos(hana::replicate<hana::tuple_tag>(*this, hana::size_c<N>)) {}
};
```

Now, you have to be careful cause that'll make a copy of each `*this` when creating a tuple in `replicate`. If you want references instead, use `reference_wrapper` like this:

```
foos(hana::replicate<hana::tuple_tag>(std::ref(*this), hana::size_c<N>))
```

and then make sure that the constructor of each thing in `FooTuple` can be constructed from a `reference_wrapper` (which is the case if they take a reference).

Comment: hana never ceases to amaze me :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the simplest way - but you might try [std::index_sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to do that:

```
template <typename FooList>
class Bar
{
    static constexpr size_t fooListSize = decltype(hana::size(std::declval<FooList>()))::value;
    template <std::size_t ...I>
    Bar(std::index_sequence<I...>) : foos{(I, *this)...} {}

public:
    using FooTuple = typename decltype(hana::unpack(FooList(), hana::template_<hana::tuple>))::type;

    Bar() : Bar(std::make_index_sequence<fooListSize>{}) {}

    FooTuple foos;
};
```

Comment: I always forget about the comma operator

Comment: People always forget about `hana::replicate` :-)